# How far will my film counter read?

Tags: film

Camera: Yashica Electro 35cc

Do film counters have a hard stop or will it just circle back to S or 1?

I'm afraid that my film counter will have a hard-stop somewhere after "36". I was shooting blanks and holding the film-release button during winding as I was having issues with my flash. I did this about 10 times or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The counter will stop when the take-up reel can no longer pull any more film out of the cartridge. That's where the "hard stop" is. The counter itself is usually just a wheel that turns as long as the take-up reel can, usually with a gear or two in between, because the take-up reel obviously makes multiple full revolutions for a single (partial) revolution of the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Every film camera I've had would move to frame 37 or 38, then stop.  I could use film beyond that but the counter would remain motionless. With the right cartridge, you could self load rolls of 39 or 40, especially if your camera had tight frame spacing.

With this technique I could get 19 rolls of 38 out of a 100 foot spool.  Part of the trick was learning how to just barely use enough film to be taken up.